# Creating an array of generic stacks

Tags: java, arrays, generics

```
Stack<E>[] stacks = {new Stack<Bed>(), new Stack<Bookshelves>(), 
                     new Stack<Chair>(), new Stack<Desk>(), new Stack<Table>()};
```

For class I had to make my own Stack class that takes in whatever object I specify.
As per specification, I have to put all the Stacks into an array.

But, when I try to create an Array of Stacks, I get a "cannot find symbol: class E" error.

What can I do to create an array of generic stacks?

Comment: You cannot create an array of generics.  But what would you want to do with it if you could?

Comment: You're almost certainly better off creating a `List` of `Stacks`.  (Although for your particular case, I frankly think you shouldn't create an array or list at all, but should keep the lists of the different types as explicit, separate variables.)

Answer (score 6):

Generic type declarations such as <E> only work when you are defining a class, like

```
public class Stack<E>{
 // etc.
}
```

To create an array of Stacks like you are doing, you could either use the wildcard generic:

```
Stack<?>[] stacks = {new Stack<Bed>(), new Stack<Bookshelves>(), new Stack<Chair>(), new Stack<Desk>(), new Stack<Table>()};
```

Or if all your objects inside the stacks share a common inheritance, you could narrow down the wildcard with something like

```
Stack<? extends Furniture>[] stacks = {new Stack<Bed>(), new Stack<Bookshelves>(), new Stack<Chair>(), new Stack<Desk>(), new Stack<Table>()};
```

Comment: `Stack<?>[]` works, but `Stack<? extends Furniture>[]` doesn't because you cannot create generic arrays, at least not with that nice short syntax :/